# Ethernet cable to DB15 connector

Tags: ethernet, prototyping

Morning Overflowers,

For a specific in-house application for my company, I need to be able to make a Gigabit ethernet connection go through DB15 connectors, as seen bellow.

[image]

Here is what I'm trying to achieve:
[image]

For the first version, I just cut in half a cat 5e ethernet cable. I did not care too much about the pin-out from the cable to the DB15 connector and in the end I ended up having a 10MBit/s data rate, which is super low. Also my cable was super short, 2m in total.

For the second version I used a 5m cat 6 cable for one side, and the remain of the other cat 5e cable (resoldered) for the other side. I was more careful about the pinout and used the 4 left most pins to place the ethernet pairs as seen here:

[image]

The data rate is this time 100 MBits/s, but still not 1 GBits/s.

Before going through a 3rd version I thought I'd use my brain a little. I noticed while soldering that although inside a cat 5e/cat 6 cable there are 4 pairs, not all of them are side by side on the RJ45 socket as seen on figure bellow where blue and green wires are a bit mixed.
[image]

There is probably a reason for that arrangement and putting pairs together other that inside the cable itself is not probably a good idea, which leads to my question.
For version 3, should I just keep pin 1 to 8 in that order and solder them to the DB15 connector on adjacent pins?

More generally I am aware that unless the DB15 section is super short I won't be able to maintain Gibabit ethernet due to noise and other problems caused by unmatched pairs on that section.

I am open to any suggestion or tips or anything :)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

After trial and errors, it turned out that it works fine if you arrange pairs to match a RJ45 connector (like on the figure "ethernet plug wiring"). The quality of the cable is probably not the one of a perfect 5e/6 cable but my computer can negociate a Gbits connection and transfer files over the network at speeds way above 10 MB/s reaching 50 MB/s. I always soldered more section with various connectors and it worked fine too.